# how to get the end of a string from indexA to indexB (using split()) in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

`"$warn @Test use of bad language"`

and I want to get the part from 'use' to 'language' (from index 2 to index x)

How can I do that with differnent parts after the `@Test` and with different length each time?
I'm new to JS and it might be super easy / dumb, but I need to know. Thx!

**i tried message.slice(2, message.length - 1). i found an answer though.**

Comment: you should look look or skim through the doc first and have some try, it could be easier to help after you have some effort

Comment: I tried, but I wasn't able to get the result I want

Comment: yeah cool, just feel free to include the snippet of what you have tried in the comment

Comment: i tried `message.slice(2, message.length - 1)`. i found an answer though.

Comment: you are going the right way, because `message` is string so that `slice` would result in `arn @Test use of bad language`. Before `slice` you should split it in tokens, then after `slice`, `join` them back to get your expected result `message.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ')`. About `slice`, no need to provide second param if you just want to slice it till the end

Comment: thank you. i included what i tried in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into different bits for this using [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const [command, mention, ...args] = message.content.split(" ")

const reason = args.join(" ")

// command = "$warn"
// mention = "@Test"
// reason = "use of bad language"
```

Using [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) here makes it easier to give a readable name to different parts of the message content